# C++ Shell multiple pipelines are not working?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, unix

I have worked on pipelines in C++ and I managed to get a single pipeline working. I am struggling a bit to get multiple pipelines working. I have no idea where it is actually going wrong.

An example that I have used to test single pipelines:

```
ls -l | grep test
```

An example that I have used to test multiple pipelines:

```
ls -l | grep test | grep test2
```

The first command works fine for me.
However, the second command does literally nothing for me.

EDIT 1-6-2019: I am going to try to work with this pseudocode

```
left_pipe = NULL
right_pipe = NULL

for each command:

    if not last:
        right_pipe = pipe()

    fork():
        child:
            if left_pipe is not NULL:
                STDIN = left_pipe.read
            if right_pipe is not NULL:
                STDOUT = right_pipe.write
            left_pipe.close_W()
            right_pipe.close_R()
            execute()
            left_pipe.close_RW()
            //Move right pipe to the left side for the next command
            left_pipe = right_pipe
end
```

I would appreciate any insight/help.

Thanks in forward.

Comment: Aside: 5 levels of nesting leads to unreadable code. Look into refactoring your `execute` method.

Comment: Will look into it afterwards.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing? Like the program exits immediately or keeps running?

Comment: @Quimby Should have explained it, my bad. I've just printed the status after a program gets executed in the shell. If I am executing ls -l | grep test | grep test2, then I get the following: -> Program test2 ended with status code 256. However, the program keeps running and it can take my input.

Comment: You're calling `dup2ReadPipe` before you create the pipe!  Call `pipe` first.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell, Will test tomorrow.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I have tested it. Now, it seems to do a little bit more. If I now do: ls -l | grep test | grep test2, then it will print the following: Program grep ended with code 256 (DOES NOT print test), Program grep ended with code 0 (DOES print test2). Any idea why it does not print the test?

Answer (score 1):

As @AndyG said, please refactor the code, it's messy, redundant and error-prone. Here are those errors:

- You are not closing the pipes. `READPIPE`,
  `WRITEPIPE` file descriptors are still open, which keeps the reader
  running. **`EOF` is read only if all write ends are closed.**
- Opening pipes in the child does not make sense, there's no way to pass them onto the next one.
- During execution of a middle command, there are two actives pipes - reading end of the left pipe as input. Writing end of the right pipe as output.

In pseudo-code you want to be doing something like this:

```
left_pipe = NULL
right_pipe = NULL

for each command:

    if not last:
        right_pipe = pipe()

    fork():
        child:
            if left_pipe is not NULL:
                STDIN = left_pipe.read
            if right_pipe is not NULL:
                STDOUT = right_pipe.write
            left_pipe.close_W()
            right_pipe.close_R()
            execute()
            left_pipe.close_RW()
            //Move right pipe to the left side for the next command
            left_pipe = right_pipe
end
```

Plus some error checking, `close_` should ignore already closed/non-existing pipes. Closing in the child is important otherwise the child would keep itself alive because it would block on `left_pipe.read` which would be waiting the `left_pipe.write` **( held by the same child)** end to write something.

I hope that you agree this is also more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. Indeed it is way more readable. Somehow, I thought it would be cleaner to split it into methods. I will look into it tomorrow and keep you updated.